# Detecting request without using document.domain

Tags: javascript, security, cakephp, cross-domain

I have a script placed in a website.

```
<script>
var domain = document.domain;
/* script related to website...*/
</script>
```

This returns the website domain to my site using some script.
Now, how can we detect the domain name without using document.domain. I cannot use document.domain as part of variable as it can easily be changed by anyone and script is no more secure. How can I check whether my script is placed in  designated website.I am having list of website names in database? I am using cakephp framework.

Comment: Only the subdomain part can be changed, changed as in _removed_. The TLD cannot be changed, ie `foo.bar.example.com` could be changed to `bar.example.com` and `example.com`, but to nothing else, `baz.bar.example.com`, `example.org`, `whatever.com`, that's all not possible, the browser will throw an error if you try something like that. On a side note, you should get used to the idea that client side script will never be "secure". What's so special about the script that your are trying to protect?

Comment: If changing the domain makes your script no longer secure, I'd think about rewriting your script.